# Renamed docker image and now I cant start the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

As title says I was renaming one of my docker images I built using Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml using the command `docker tag old-image-name new-image-name`, after that I used `docker images` to check on my current images and I had BOTH the old and the new one.

I removed the old one using `docker image rm IMAGE_ID` and since then I've been getting the following error `failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount511639725/Dockerfile: no such file or directory` when I try to start the container.

I've tried everything, other containers start without problem and I've successfully ran this container in the past. This are the only changes I've made, nothing changed on my Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml.

I've tried removing the images related to this stack to build again many times. also tried rebuilding the image with Dockerfile alone (not trough docker-compose.yml).

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the specific commands you're running?  The error you quote is a build-time error and means the Dockerfile is missing; it wouldn't be caused by renaming an image and you wouldn't encounter it trying to run a container.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means it cannot find your docker file. It usually happens when its named incorrectly, make sure your docker file is named exactly as "Dockerfile"

Comment: Thanks for the reply! my file is named correctly tho, its "Dockerfile" no extension no dot, and I haven't modified it but the error started showing after the rename

Comment: okay could you run "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build" and post your output. That should display the error happening within docker and provide more information

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, and it pains me that was very dumb on my side.

When I had the container running I was adding some network changes on my docker-compose.yml to use NGINX with the django project.

When I did those changes I changed `build: .` to `build: ~/path/to/folder`, I thought it would be able to recognize that path but apparently it has to be absolute or use the `.`

**Solution: reverting to `build: .` or `build: /home/your_user/path/to/folder` asuming your folder is in /home/your_user/*, avoid using ~**

Thanks for the replies everyone